# React - setting the required attribute of an <input> element based on a prop value

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'd like to set the required attribute on the  element based on a prop value isRequired that is passed to the component and false by default

Input component:

```
    export default function Input({
      name,
      id,
      type,
      labelText,
      isRequired=false,
      validationFn,
      errorMsg,
      ...props
    }) {

 return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name} className="font-bold">
        {labelText}
      </label>
      <input   
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        type={type}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        value={val}
        {isRequired && 'required'}
        {...props}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

However,

```
{isRequired && 'required'}
```

does not work. I'm getting the error:

> *Unexpected token, expected "..."*

I've also tried

```
{isRequired ? 'required' : ''}
```

but still the same.

What works is:

```
{...(isRequired ? { required: true } : {})}
```

Can someone tell me what the issue is and why the line above works?

Comment: the correct way to write this would be ‘required={isRequired}’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Incorrect syntax in first two expressions**

`{isRequired && 'required'}` and `{isRequired ? 'required' : ''}` throws an error because JSX expects the required (or any other attribute for that matter) to be in a key-value pair format which the above two expressions are not.

***Why `{...(isRequired ? { required: true } : {})}` works***

The expression `{...(isRequired ? { required: true } : {})}` works because in the case of `isRequired` being `true`, this expression spreads a key-value pair (which is what JSX expects), and in the case `isRequired` is `false` it spreads an empty object which is a valid syntax and doesn't add the `required` attribute to the `input`

The more idiomatic solution for this would be to directly assign the `isRequired` prop to the `required` input attribute as following

`required={isRequired}`